# Using Tag to pass info between widgets with GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a flextable containing data about events. The first cell of each row contains a button with an Id reffering to the event   (i.e. **btn_5_qaoebqiblqr9ss0182e7lrn89k@google.com** where **5** = rownumber and **qaoebqiblqr9ss0182e7lrn89k@google.com** = eventId).

```
function onClickShowEvent(e)
{ // Handle the event clicked in eventsTable

   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();      
   var btnDelete = app.getElementById(btn_deleteEvent);
   var eventId   = e.parameter.source;
   btn.setVisible(true).setTag(eventId);  // Tag will be set to     btn_5_qaoebqiblqr9ss0182e7lrn89k@google.com

  // Check if tag has been set
  var test = btn.getTag();
  Logger.log('eventId= ' + eventId + '   setTag succes= ' + (eventId == test));
   .....
}
```

It turns out the tag has been set succesful at this stage.

In the eventhandler of the button I want to 'inform' 2 other buttons  (with ids btn_updateEvent and btn_deleteEvent) about what element in the flextable has been selected, in order to know what event must be handled after the button will be clicked.
I thought I could use the tags for that, but it doesn't work.

```
function onClickDeleteEvent(e)
{
var func = 'onClickDeleteEvent';
   var app      = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var source   = e.parameter.source;           // Will be btn_deleteEvent
   var btn      = app.getElementById(source);
   var eventId  = app.getElementById(wid_eventsTable).getTag(); // returns   eventId = null

Logger.log('in ' + func + '    source= ' + e.parameter.source + '   eventId= ' + eventId);

   return appLocal;
}
```

But here it turns out that getTag retrieves **null**.
How can that be and what can I do to 'pass' the info I need?
I would like to avoid using a hidden field.

**Edit-1**
If I change the id of a button I receive **Error encountered. an unexpected error occurred.**

```
 var btnDelete = appLocal.getElementById('btn_deleteEvent');
 var infoEvent = bell + numRow + bell + event.getId(); // I use 'bell' for delimiting fields
 var newId = 'btn_deleteEvent' + infoEvent;
 btnDelete.setId(newId);
```

So the trick providing info using the name(s) of the button(s) does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the TAG of a widget is available as a value in the eventInfo parameter in the form `tagValue = e.parameter.widgetName_TAG`

in your case it would be an issue since button don't have a name property. I suggest you use another approach llike a tag on another widget or a hidden widget to store the info you need.

Comment: I ended up using a hidden widget and setting its id to 'numRow + bell + event.getId()'  . In 'onClickDeleteButton' I split the id of the hidden (using 'bell' = /x07 as delimiter) and delete the event.